# XForms add hit/mouseover to itemset labels

Tags: xpath, xforms, xsltforms

Is it possible to add a mouseover or xforms:hint to an itemset label? Using XSLTForms version 1.3. Just adding <xf:hint> under <xf:itemset> does not seem to do the trick, wondering if someone else has solved this in another way?